# Canvas' clearRect() weird bug detected

Tags: javascript, android, html, canvas

I am drawing 200 pictures per requestAnimationFrame() on the following code:

```
<canvas id = "canvas"></canvas>
<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
height = window.innerHeight;
width = window.innerWidth
canvas.width = width; 
canvas.height = height; 

playerY = height / 10;
playerX = 20;
var diamond = new Image();
diamond.src = "https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2016/05/10/762776_poker_512x512.png";

var direction = 1;
move();

function move(){

    if(playerX > width)
    direction = -12;
    if(playerX < 0) direction = 12;

    playerX+= direction;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    for(var i = 1; i < 1000; i+=50){ //simply draw all within 50 y margin
        ctx.drawImage(diamond,0, 0, 128, 128, playerX, playerY + i, 70, 70);
    }                                       
    requestAnimationFrame(move);

}

</script>
```

As you can see I have clearRect clearing my entire screen with this line:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
```

now on my actual game I don't actually clear my entire screen, only the parts that need to be redrawn, so it looks something like that:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height - 50); //this is in my bugged game
```

this way i don't need to redraw static parts of my games (usually background and buttons).

Well I noticed a bug on my "height - 50" approach, on some devices and on some circumstances(ill list them in a sec) the pixels of EVERY draw on my canvas start dancing. example:

https://s30.postimg.org/su18gn7ox/bug.png

This bug is noticeable on medium devices not running on 60FPS or simply if you run this code while a 4K video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNJdPyoqt8U) is running in your 2nd screen or some heavy browser app is running is in the background. This bug drove me nuts for 2 days as I am developing for android and it happens on some medium devices. 
Any fix for this problem is appreciated.

Comment: What's the 50? Should that be a function of the device size?

Comment: You mean height - 50? just an example of clearRect reduction. simply speaking not clearing the entire screen.

Comment: Not sure where the bug comes from, but for a workaround : use offscren canvases. Each frame clear your whole presented canvas, draw the canvas containing the static drawings on it, then draw your updates.Multiple clearRects won't give you any better performances than a single drawImage.

Comment: But still a lot of things have to be done because of this bug, for example because I use a background so I must do clearRect(width, height) and only then draw the background for example, instead of just drawing the background(the bug will happen otherwise).